# Modify and access a var from another class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two Scenes and Two Swift files with two different classes. One of them called `GameViewController` and the other one is called `FelicidadesViewController`.

In `GameViewController` I have a `Int` var called `round` which I have initialized with the number 1.
So, in the same class I have a button when I push on it, if the condition is true, appear the second viewcontroller called `FelicidadesViewController`.

I want to pass the var called `round` to the second viewcontroller and in this view sum one to the `round` when I push the button that I have created in this class called `nextLevel`.

How can I modify and access to a variable to another class in different ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use prepareForSegue.

1. Add identifier to your segue (click the arrow between two screens in storyboard and set identifier in right panel)
2. In second VC (view cotnroller) make var round
3. In first VC override func prepareForSegue

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier=="yourIdentifier"){
        if let nVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondVC{
            nVC.round = self.round
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I created a segue called "MostrarFelicidades". and I have created a var called "round" in the secondVC as you told me but I get a warning which say that round is not member of my second VC.

Comment: And did you change secondVC to FelicidadesViewController ? I wrote secondVC just so the sample would be universal.

Comment: Yes, where you had written "secondVC" I have changed it by "FelicidadesViewController".

Comment: Try to run it anyway, mayby it's just bug in Xcode.

Comment: I think that I have explained wrong. My intention is that the value of "round" of the first VC pass to the secondVC. In the secondVC, where a push the button for come back to the firstVC sum one to "round" and in the firstVC appear "round + 1". Before you have right and it's work but I don't know how the program save the new value of "round" in the firstVC. I'm a beginner and I don't any idea.

Comment: So every time when firstVC appears the round value in to should be +1? You can just init it with 0 and override viewDidAppear (dont forgot to call super viewDidAppear) with round += 1.

Comment: I can't realize that way but i created a struct with a static var called "round" and now it's work. Thank you so much. I don't know whether it is a good way but my method is work!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Can you mark my answer with green tick? Thanks

Comment: Of course. and thank you so much again. you have been a great help.